# How to make an integral and reproduce its graph

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration

How by Mathematica we can make the integral, equation (101) in

[arxiv:1307.5949](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1307.5949.pdf)

$
H_0(t-t_0) = \int^{\frac{a}{a_0}}_1 ~ \frac{da’}{\sqrt{ \frac{\Omega_r}{a’^2}  +  \frac{\Omega_m}{a’} + \Omega_\Lambda a’^2 + (1-\Omega_{total})}} 
$

and reproduce the graph FIG. (2) of the scale factor of $\Lambda$CDM model versus the Hubble parameter $H_0(t-t_0)$ (the black curve) ?
[image]

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please post the equation by Mathematica code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using easy friedly notation:

```
ClearAll["`*"]
OT = 1; OM = 0.315; OL = 0.685; OR = 1 - OM - OL;
INT = Integrate[1/Sqrt[OR/x^2 + OM/x + OL*x^2 + (1 - OT)], {x, 1, a0},GenerateConditions -> False]

(*-0.950985 + (0.805496 Sqrt[a0] Sqrt[0.459854/a0 + 1. a0^2]
ArcSinh[1.47465 a0^(3/2)])/Sqrt[0.459854 + 1. a0^3]*)

ContourPlot[H0 == INT, {H0, -2, 2}, {a0, 0, 3}, FrameLabel -> Automatic, AspectRatio -> 0.6, ContourStyle -> Black]
```

[image]

**UPDATED:**

```
ClearAll["`*"]
OT = 1; OM = 0.2; OL = 0.3; OR = 1 - OM - OL;(*If OR is not a zero !*)
INT[a0_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[1/Sqrt[OR/x^2 + OM/x + OL*x^2 + (1 - OT)], {x, 1, a0}]
ContourPlot[H0 == INT[a0], {H0, -2, 2}, {a0, 0, 3}, 
FrameLabel -> Automatic, AspectRatio -> 0.6, ContourStyle -> Black]
```